# array coding error in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a set of values

```
y_train=["User","Bot","User","Bot",.......]
y_pred=["Bot","User","User","Bot".........]
```

I want to generate an array which returns 1 if the values of y_train[i] and t_pred[i] dont match.Both y_train and y_pred consist of same no of values

That is array indicator should be:

```
indicator=[1,1,0,0..........]
```

I have tried

```
 indicator=0
 for i in range(len(y_train)):
      if y_train[i]!=y_pred[i]:
            indicator[i]=1
      else:
            indicator[i]=0
```

But error being shown is :

```
'int' object does not support item assignment
```

How could this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
indicator = map(lambda x,y: int(x != y), y_train, y_pred)
```

As commented, if `indicator` serves as a boolean array, you may remove the int conversion to generate a `True` & `False` array:

```
indicator = map(lambda x,y: x != y, y_train, y_pred)
```

or as suggested in the comment:

```
indicator =  map(operator.ne, y_train, y_pred)
```

Comment: __int__ conversion excluded - the best answer.

Comment: If OP needs indicator values as `True` or `False` we may remove the conversion.

Comment: OP may be unaware of that option

Comment: `operator.ne` is the same as `lambda x,y: x != y`.

Answer (score 2):

`indicator = [t != p for t, p in zip(y_train, y_pred)]`

Comment: Or just __t==p__, which is essentially integer in disguise

Comment: You don't need __int__, it just adds execution overhead. _False_ and _True_ are equivalent to 0 and 1. __1==True__ returns ... __True__ and __5+True__ will evaluate to __6__. Rule of the thumb - never convert when you don't have to (Python is not C and does not require strict explicit type castings)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared indicator as an int. Try this:

```
indicator=[]
for i in range(len(y_train)):
  if y_train[i]!=y_pred[i]:
        indicator.append(1)
  else:
        indicator.append(0)
```

Another way to do this is:

```
indicator = []
for i,j in zip(y_train,y_pred):
    if i==j:
        indicator.append(0)
    else:
        indicator.append(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, this is what you *should* do:

```
indicator = [1 if x != y else 0 for x, y in zip(y_train, y_pred)]
# or indicator = [int(x != y) for x, y in zip(y_train, y_pred)]
```

This is a list comprehension. It uses `zip` to go over the values of `y_train` and `y_pred` in parallel. For every pair of corresponding values in `y_train` and `y_pred`, `indicator` contains `1` if the values are unequal and `0` otherwise.

Now, here's what's wrong with your attempt. First, if you want `indicator` to be a list, don't make it an int:

```
#indicator=0
indicator = []
```

Second, you can't assign to indices past the end of a list. You can `append` the values instead:

```
for i in range(len(y_train)):
    if y_train[i]!=y_pred[i]:
#         indicator[i]=1
          indicator.append(1)
    else:
#         indicator[i]=0
          indicator.append(0)
```